# Is there a way to wrap UL sub-menu to div?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, wordpress-theming, html-lists

Here is my problem is there a way to wrap WordPress `UL` submenu to `div`?

WordPress output is this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
  <li>link 3
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li>Sub-link 1</li>
      <li>Sub-link 2</li>
      <li>Sub-link 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I need to get this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
  <li>link 3
    <div class="wrap">
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Sub-link 1</li>
        <li>Sub-link 2</li>
        <li>Sub-link 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`$.fn.wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$('.sub-menu').wrap('<div class="wrap">');
```